# sms api integration with php - smsedge.com telnyx.com

Tags: php

Did anyone used https://smsedge.com/ or https://telnyx.com

I am trying to use the PHP api, but no luck with smsedge .
Telnyx works like a charm but I could not find a way to send like a bulk sms.
Tryed the help section, they just posted me a link, but it doesnt work :(

```
 <?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

\Telnyx\Telnyx::setApiKey('myapikey');

\Telnyx\Message::Create([
  "from" => "TShop",
  "to" => "+4473836955xx",
  "text" => "Hello, World! visit www.google.com",
  "messaging_profile_id" => "40017370-b28d-425f-8785-92a64f52ea60"
]);
```

Is there any way to send to multiple number all at once ?
Also : I am new to php and still reading trying to figure it out .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

I struggled many hours to find a service and found one service that does bulk sms :

https://www.infobip.com/

Here is an example(just replace the `<api_key>` with your key)

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    $fields = [
        'messages' => [
            array(
                'from'         => 'infoSMS',
                'destinations' => ['to' => '1st_phone_number'],
                'text'         => 'This is first message.',
            ),
            array(
                'from'         => 'infoSMS',
                'destinations' => ['to' => '2nd_phone_number'],
                'text'         => 'This is second message.',
            ),
            array(
                'from'         => 'infoSMS',
                'destinations' => ['to' => '3rd_phone_number'],
                'text'         => 'This is third message.',
            ),
        ]
    ];
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL            => "https://qgdg2q.api.infobip.com/sms/2/text/advanced",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode($fields),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            "Authorization: App <api_key>",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json",
        ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

There is also another service which is https://smsedge.com/